# Kadane's algorithm fails to satify the condition when first number is negative

Tags: python, kadanes-algorithm

My algorithm is as shown below:

```
Initialize:
    max_so_far = 0
    max_ending_here = 0

Loop for each element of the array
  (a) max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i]
  (b) if(max_ending_here < 0)
            max_ending_here = 0
  (c) if(max_so_far < max_ending_here)
            max_so_far = max_ending_here
return max_so_far
```

On the basis of that, the code that I have written is as shown below:

```
def maxSubArraySum(a,size):

    max_so_far = 0
    max_ending_here = 0

    for i in range(0, size):
        max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i]
        if max_ending_here < 0:
            max_ending_here = 0

        # Do not compare for all elements. Compare only   
        # when  max_ending_here > 0
        elif (max_so_far < max_ending_here):
            max_so_far = max_ending_here

    return max_so_far

# Driver function to check the above function 
a = [-1,-2,-3,-4]
print ("Maximum contiguous sum is", maxSubArraySum(a,len(a))).
```

This code somehow gives me `output 0` when the `array is [-1,-2,-3,-4]`. Is there anything which I should rectify in my current code?

Comment: well... without being familiar with the algorithm, the pseudocode you show has two consecutive `if`s while your code has an `if-elif` condition, which is not the same, as in the pseudocode a variable can go into the two conditions while in the code it cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Simple idea of the Kadane's algorithm is to look for all positive
>   contiguous segments of the array (max_ending_here is used for this).
>   And keep track of maximum sum contiguous segment among all positive
>   segments (max_so_far is used for this).

As such, a list with all negative numbers will trip the algorithm. 
If you think about it though, maximum sum of all negative integer list is nothing but `max(list_of_negative_integers)`.

However, if you want to create a generic solution,

- add another variable `max_in_array` and a `flag`.
- set flag on
- loop through items

  - Keep the `max_in_array` up-to-date while looping.
  - set the flag off, if you find a positive number.
  - do the existing logic to update two variables you already have
- if the flag is off, return `max_so_far` otherwise `max_in_array`

Here is an implementation for reference:

```
def max_sub_array_sum(arr):
    max_so_far = max_ending_here = 0
    max_in_arr = arr[0]
    flag = True

    for item in arr:
        if flag:
            max_in_arr = max(max_in_arr, item)

        max_ending_here = max(0, max_ending_here + item)
        max_so_far = max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)

        if item > 0:
            flag = False

    return max_in_arr if flag else max_so_far
```

Another approach without extra vars:

```
def max_sub_array_sum(arr):
    max_so_far = curr_max = arr[0]

    for item in arr[1:]:
        curr_max = max(item, curr_max + item)
        max_so_far = max(max_so_far, curr_max)

    return max_so_far
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is all known for Shorter and readable codes With 3.0 Solution this might help you.
To Understand algorithm better watch this video:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MmGzdiKR9Y

```
def max_sub_array_sum(arr):

    kadance=[]
    #kadance[i]=arr[0]
    kadance.append(arr[0])

    for i in range(1,len(arr)):
        #kadance[i] = max(kadance[i-1]+arr[i],arr[i])
        temp = max(kadance[i-1]+arr[i],arr[i])
        kadance.append(temp)

    ans = kadance[0]

    for i in range(1,len(kadance)):
        ans = max(ans,kadance[i])

    return ans

print(max_sub_array_sum([-1,-2,-3,-4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the if statements - put the check of max before updating the array.

```
if (max_so_far < max_ending_here) 
                max_so_far = max_ending_here; 
if (max_ending_here < 0) 
                max_ending_here = 0;
```